# Connect geom_points by lines wíth keeping distance

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, scatter-plot

In `ggplot2`, I want to make an easy `geom_point()` scatter plot, with the dots connected by a line. However, I want the lines not to touch the point, as for example in [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GqTn.png) but I do not seem to manage at all in `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack but this might help

[image]

```
x=1:20
y=rnorm(20)
data=data.frame(x,y)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data,aes(x,y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(size=4,color="white")+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution; I came up myself with this approach, but the code is cumbersome if you want to plot multiple datasets, paying attention to the order of plotting ... which made me looking for a non-hack solution.

Comment: @rubenbaetens , you should provide a reproducible exemple that presents the true complexity of your problem. Otherwise, we cannot help you efficiently